# Play framework 2.2. Stress fails when compared to Tomcat 6

Tags: performance, tomcat, netty, stress-testing, playframework-2.2

Lost miserably to tomcat 6 while performing Stress testing using Gatling 2.
Our candidate REST service for stress test is a simple JSON response.

Gatling set to hit 900 users in 1 second.

Play controller code is as follows:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Promise<Result> getSamplePerf() {

    Promise<JsonNode> promiseOfJson = Promise.promise(new Function0<JsonNode>() {
        public JsonNode apply() throws Exception {
            AResponseBean aResponseBean = new AResponseBean();

            aResponseBean .setStatus("success");
            aResponseBean .setMessage("Hello World. Welcome to Gatling...");

            return Json.toJson(aResponseBean );
        }
    });

    return promiseOfJson.map(new Function<JsonNode, Result>() {
        public Result apply(JsonNode jsonNode) {
            return ok(jsonNode);
        }
    } , Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("contexts.my-dispatcher"));

}
```

Our application.conf consists of :

```
play {
     akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger", "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = ERROR
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0   
          parallelism-max = 64
          parallelism-min = 8          
        }     
      }
    }
  }
}  

  contexts {
    my-dispatcher {
        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-min = 400
            parallelism-max = 400
        }
    }
   }
```

Test results on tomcat 6 revealed :

```
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------

> t < 800 ms                                           900 (100%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                   0 (  0%)
> t > 1200 ms                                            0 (  0%)
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)
================================================================================
```

and those on inbuilt Netty :

```
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------

> t < 800 ms                                            22 (  2%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                 232 ( 25%)
> t > 1200 ms                                          646 ( 71%)
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)
================================================================================
```

Kindly help us boost play performance.

Comment: I think you'd get a better chance to get help if you'd ask on the Play! Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework

Comment: Done. But I see the forum seldom answering to basic play framework queries. Anyway , trying my luck once more in play forum.

Comment: When you ran the tests did you run Play in production mode (`play start`)?

Comment: I distributed the Play app using "play dist" command , and ran "bash abc" script under "target\universal\tmp\bin" folder in Centos 6 machine.